# QGIS failing to save and export selected layers as GeoPackage getting an error message

Tags: qgis

Failing to save and export selected layers getting this error message:

> Export to vector file failed. Error: Creation of data source failed
> (OGR error: sqlite3_open(Chichi_District.gpkg) failed: unable to open
> database file)

Comment: do you have write permission to that directory?

Comment: If you are opening a QGIS project via vpn and you lost connection for a short time, it may be, that this error occurs.

Comment: i am using it offline on my PC